# Space between 2 vertices on a heightmap

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am working on a infinite world generated with Perlin Noise, Java and LWJGL. But I am having a problem, it is kinda hard to explain, so I made a video: http://youtu.be/D_NUBJZ_5Kw Obviously the problem is the black spaces in between all the pieces of ground.

I already tried making all the values doubles instead of floats, but that didn't fix it.

Here is a piece of code I am using:

```
float height2, height = (float)getHeight(x, y);

height2 = (float) ((getHeight(x-1, y+1) + height) / 2);
vertexhelper.addVertexColorAndTexture(x, height2, y+1, r, g, b, a, 0f, 1f);

height2 = (float) ((getHeight(x+1, y+1) + height) / 2);
vertexhelper.addVertexColorAndTexture(x+1, height2, y+1, r, g, b, a, 1f, 1f);

height2 = (float) ((getHeight(x+1, y-1) + height) / 2);
vertexhelper.addVertexColorAndTexture(x+1, height2, y, r, g, b, a, 1f, 0f);

height2 = (float) ((getHeight(x-1, y-1) + height) / 2);
vertexhelper.addVertexColorAndTexture(x, height2, y, r, g, b, a, 0f, 0f);
```

I loop through this at the initialization of a chunk with x->16 and y->16. `vertexhelper` is a class I made that just puts everything in a array.

(I am using floats here, but that's after doing the maths, so that shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: Does it also occur if you color the tiles green and don't use any texture?

Comment: @Matthias Yes, I have the same problem without textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to take 4 places on the heightmap in account instead of 2. So instead of

```
height2 = (float) ((getHeight(x-1, y-1) + height) / 2);
```

I had to use

```
height2 = (float) ((getHeight(x, y-1) + getHeight(x-1, y) + getHeight(x-1, y-1) + height) / 4);
```

That fixed it.

Comment: Remember that you can accept your own answers (won't gain you rep), to mark it as answered.

Comment: @datenwolf I know that, but only after 2 days. Thanks